# Is there a simple way to make similar 1-Line Calculator?

Tags: python, calculator

As a Beginner, I was trying to make 1-line Calculator using Python... And I come to this.
I converted the user input into list and then used the list elements to get the result.
For example in case if multiplication I took the elements before the sign, combined them and then the elements after the sign and combined them.Then Multiply the together.

```
question = list(input("Enter Your Question: "))
def convert(list): 
    s = [str(i) for i in list] 
    combined = int("".join(s)) 
    list = combined
    return(combined)
multiply = "*"
add = "+"
substract = "-"
divide = "/"
if multiply in question:
    for multiply in question:
        position1 = question.index("*")
        before_num = question[0: int(position1)]
        aft = len(question)
        after_num = question[int(position1) + 1: int(aft)]
        num_before = convert(before_num)
        num_after = convert(after_num)
        print(int(num_before) * int(num_after))
        break
elif add in question:
    for add in question:
        position1 = question.index("+")
        before_num = question[0: int(position1)]
        aft = len(question)
        after_num = question[int(position1) + 1: int(aft)]
        num_before = convert(before_num)
        num_after = convert(after_num)
        print(int(num_before) + int(num_after))
        break
elif substract in question:
    for substract in question:
        position1 = question.index("-")
        before_num = question[0: int(position1)]
        aft = len(question)
        after_num = question[int(position1) + 1: int(aft)]
        num_before = convert(before_num)
        num_after = convert(after_num)
        print(int(num_before) - int(num_after))
        break
elif divide in question:
    for divide in question:
        position1 = question.index("/")
        before_num = question[0: int(position1)]
        aft = len(question)
        after_num = question[int(position1) + 1: int(aft)]
        num_before = convert(before_num)
        num_after = convert(after_num)
        print(int(num_before) / int(num_after))
        break
else:
    print("Check Your Question Again")
end_program_ans = input("Press Enter to continue")
```

This Works Perfect but is there a simpler way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
read_data = input("Enter Your Question: ")
if "*" in read_data:
    data1,data2 = read_data.split("*")
    print(float(data1)*float(data2))
elif "+" in read_data:
    data1,data2 = read_data.split("+")
    print(float(data1)+float(data2))
elif "-" in read_data:
    data1,data2 = read_data.split("-")
    print(float(data1)-float(data2))
elif "/" in read_data:
    data1,data2 = read_data.split("/")
    print(float(data1)/float(data2))
else:
    print("Please Enter Proper data")
```